# How to create a nested dictionary from multiple list?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I combine three separate list into one single dictionary?
Currently I have three operator inputs, where each input is split into a list.

```
item_input = input("Enter products seperated by space")
price_input = input("Enter price seperated by space")
stock_input = input("Enter stock seperated by space")

items = item_input.split()  
price = price_input.split()
stock = stock_input.split()
```

I assume my first step would be to combine the **price_input** and **stock_input** into one dictionary first, and then nest them into the **products_input**.

I've tried using the fromkey method to make the **price_input** in its own dictionary to start with but the keys and values are in the opposite positions that I want

Example code:

```
price = [1,2,3]
price_dict = dict.fromkeys (price, "price")

#Output = {1: 'price', 2: 'price', 3: 'price'}
#Inteded output = {"price": 1, "price": 2, "price": 3}
```

This is the intended final output that I need.

```
products = {
   "apple": {"price": 3.5, "stock": 134},
   "banana": {"price": 6.82, "stock": 52},
   "cake": {"price": 23, "stock": 5}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` item, price and stock together and then just use a dictionary comprehension:

```py
items = input("Items: ").split()
prices = map(float, input("Prices: ").split())
stocks = map(int, input("Stocks: ").split())

products = {
    item: {"price": price, "stock": stock} 
    for item, price, stock in zip(items, prices, stocks)
}
```

However, it might be better if the user could enter items one by one instead of having to add all at once so you could use a loop for that, the user inputs values separated by comma and to exit just doesn't type anything, simply pressers enter key.

```py
products = {}

new_product = input("Item, price, stock: ")
while new_product:
    item, price, stock = new_product.split(",")
    products[item.strip()] = {"price": float(price), "stock": int(stock)}
    new_product = input("Item, price, stock: ")
```

Comment: And if I wanted to add multiple products I assume a while loop will work just fine?

Comment: You can already add multiple products using this, however, I'm writing another solution that uses a while loop, yes @GohKianSeen

Comment: Awesome, thx a ton for the quick and concise response :)

Comment: @GohKianSeen sure, also that while loop solution had an issue, it's fixed now

Comment: One last question, would I be able to change any null value inputs in price and stocks to a 0?

Comment: can't the user just input 0?

Comment: they could, but would it be complicated to still do that?

Comment: not particularly, no, just do a simple check if the entered value matches the string `"null"` before it's converted to a number and then set it to 0

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
answer={x[0]: {"price": x[1], "stock" : x[2]} for x in zip(items, price, stock)}
```

This is similar to a list comprehension but returns a dictionary.

`zip(items, price, stock)` turns the three lists into a single list of tuples. Actually it is probably an generator - but here the effect here is the same.
Then it just iterate over this joined List/generator and construct each entry of the final dictionary.